# How can I set COLLATION of a field to utf8_general_ci with GORM?

Tags: mysql, go-gorm

I would like to have a string-type field in a MySQL database which is case-insenstive and unique. I used the following model:

```
type User struct {
    Id             int64  `json:"id" sql:"AUTO_INCREMENT"`
    Email          string `json:"email" sql:"unique_index"`
}
```

which makes `Email` unique, but

```
type User struct {
    Id             int64  `json:"id" sql:"AUTO_INCREMENT"`
    Email          string `json:"email" sql:"unique_index;COLLATION(utf8_general_ci)"`
}
```

seems to have no effect.

How can I set COLLATION of a field to utf8_general_ci with GORM?

Comment: @RickJames In how far is your comment related to my question?

Comment: I don't know `GORM`; it is easier for me to talk in `mysql`.  Providing the output of that `SHOW` would give me more information about what you are doing.

Comment: @RickJames If you don't know GORM, you cannot help me. I can solve this in MySQL. My problem is that I don't know how to solve it with GORM.

Comment: Beware that the *local part* of an email address is, in theory at least, case-sensitive (albeit that many, if not most, MDAs do in fact ignore lettercase).  Thus whilst you *probably* won't encounter any problems by using a `_ci` collation on an email column, it's *conceivable* that you might.  Probably best not to use `_ci` collations at all in this case, although that of course does not invalidate your question.

Comment: did you ever find a solution? I've the same need using golang gorm

Comment: @Alessio No, i didn't

Comment: I've found a way, check my answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the sql tag in the field you want to change, like this:

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name `sql:"type:VARCHAR(5) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci"`
}
```